# Prevent text overflowing DIV when parent DIV width is set by percentage

Tags: css, overflow

I know there are a number of similar posts but I have read over 20 and the solutions I've found are not helping me.

Some of my content has a layout similar to the one I've detailed here:

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2ma3qwx7/8/)

There is a container div **"Strip"** holding  3 child divs; `img`,`title`,`description`. The contain div has a fixed width of 944px.

- The first div `img` is a fixed size. This works fine.
- The second div `title` should auto size to accommodate the length of the title. This works fine.
- The third div `description` should fill the remainder of the unused `Strip` Div *without overflowing*. This is not working.

I can get it to work if I set the `description` div to a fixed width size but that doesn't help me as the size will change depending on how long the title is.

I'm sure this is very simple but I've gone through so many iterations with no luck.

CSS:

````
  font-weight: bold;
}

.strip {
  width: 944px;
  max-width: 944px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: Solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  max-height: 28px;
  white-space: nowrap;   

}

.img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-wrap: hidden;


}

 .img p {   
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;   
  overflow: hidden;

 }


.title {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
  max-height: 28px;


}

.title p {


  white-space: nowrap;   
  overflow: hidden;
}


.description {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  max-height: 28px;


}

.description p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;   
  overflow: hidden;
}```


**HTML:**

```<html>
  <div class="strip">    


    <div class="img">
      <p>
        Test
      </p>
    </div>

     <div class="title">
      <p>
        Rotten Tomatoes
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>
        Rotten Tomatoes, home of the Tomatometer, is the most trusted measurement of quality for Movies & TV. Rotten Tomatoes, home of the Tomatometer, is the most trusted measurement of quality for Movies & TV.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</html>```
````

Comment: never understand why people will make a fiddle and not a stack snippet, especially when it's just html and css

Comment: Also, what should happen to the text in the third element when it *should* overflow. Should it wrap or be clipped using ellipsis?

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the information. I have updated the question although I can't seem to separate the css and HTML snippets.

When it should overflow it should use ellipsis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.strip {
  width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  margin:auto;
}

.img {
  border: 1PX solid red;
  width: 50px;
}

.title {
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.description {
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-width: 0;
}

.description p {
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="strip">


  <div class="img">
    IMG
  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <p>
      Rotten Tomatoes
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    <p>
      Rotten Tomatoes, home of the Tomatometer, is the most trusted measurement of quality for Movies & TV. Rotten Tomatoes, home of the Tomatometer, is the most trusted measurement of quality for Movies & TV.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - that works, extremely helpful. I was just reading about Flex to see if it could solve my problems.